# Separating all IPv4 addresses from goog.json into a list with Python

Tags: python, json, list, keyerror

I am trying to get all IPv4 addresses from the goog.json file (https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json) into a list in Python. This is what I am writing

```
import json
import requests

ip_ranges_google = requests.get('https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json').json()['prefixes']

google_ips = [item['ipv4Prefix'] for item in ip_ranges_google]
```

What I get back is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Soumik Work\Code\get_google_ips.py", line 6, in <module>
    google_ips = [item['ipv4Prefix'] for item in ip_ranges_google]
  File "c:\Soumik Work\Code\get_google_ips.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    google_ips = [item['ipv4Prefix'] for item in ip_ranges_google]
KeyError: 'ipv4Prefix'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am a total newbie to Python, so a little help please?

Answer (score 0):

Some items don't contain key `ipv4Prefix`, but only `ipv6Prefix`. To get only items with `ipv4Prefix` you can do:

```py
import json
import requests

ip_ranges_google = requests.get(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json"
).json()["prefixes"]

google_ips = [
    item["ipv4Prefix"] for item in ip_ranges_google if "ipv4Prefix" in item
]

print(*google_ips, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
...

208.68.108.0/22
208.81.188.0/22
208.117.224.0/19
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.73.80.0/20
216.239.32.0/19
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because there is some dicts that does not have "ipv4Prefix".
Some of them say "ipv6Prefix"

Insert a try except to catch your error so that it doesn't break.

```py
import requests

ip_ranges_google = requests.get('https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json').json()['prefixes']

google_ips = []


for item in ip_ranges_google:
    try:
        google_ips.append(item['ipv4Prefix'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

print(google_ips)
```